# Is it possible to pray that a previous prayer not be answered?

Tags: tefilla

Sometimes we pray for things that we later change our mind about.

Is it possible to later regret that prayer and pray that Hashem *not answer the previous prayer*?

Hypothetical for the most extreme case I can think of: When Moshe prayed for Hashem to blot Him out of His book, imagine Hashem had agreed. Could Moshe have possibly prayed "actually, please don't blot me out of your book, I regret saying that"?

*As a bonus, what about praying that someone else's prayer doesn't get answered?*

Comment: Choni Hameagel kind of did this but not exactly. Taanis 3:7

Comment: Yoma 53b ומתפלל תפלה קצרה בבית החיצון. מאי מצלי? ... רב אחא בריה דרבא מסיים בה משמיה דרב יהודה: לא יעדי עביד שולטן מדבית יהודה, ולא יהיו עמך ישראל צריכין לפרנס זה מזה, ולא תכנס לפניך תפלת עוברי דרכים.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's interesting for the bonus question thank you. Seems from the rest of the sugya that this works if you are more holy than the other! Perhaps we can extrapolate, am I holier now than I was when I made the first prayer, that I wish to nullify?